# Import annotations from one pdf file to another using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to import annotations from one pdf file to another using Excel VBA. I have written the below code

```
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set Part1Document = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set Part2Document = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    
    Part1Document.Open ("C:\Users\dell\Downloads\trial\Donohue_Article heat transfer and pressure drop.pdf")
    Part2Document.Open ("C:\Users\dell\Downloads\trial\Shell Pressure Drop.pdf")
    
    Set DocPage = Part1Document.AcquirePage(0)
    Set DocPage2 = Part2Document.AcquirePage(0)
    
    numberOfPages = DocPage2.GetNumAnnots()

    For i = 0 To annotNumber - 1
        Set Annot = DocPage.GetAnnot(i)
        Set Rect = CreateObject("AcroExch.Rect")
        Set oldRect = Annot.GetRect()
        annotType = Annot.GetSubtype()
        With Rect
            .bottom = oldRect.bottom
            .Left = oldRect.Left
            .Right = oldRect.Right
            .Top = oldRect.Top
        End With

'If I used AddAnnot, it always returns false and no comment is imported
        myAnnot = DocPage2.AddAnnot(i, Annot)

'If I used AddNewAnnot, the object myAnnot returns nothing, and hence the subsequent code breaks
        Set myAnnot = DocPage2.AddNewAnnot(i, annotType, Rect)
        With myAnnot
            .SetContents (Annot.GetContents())
            .SetTitle (Annot.GetTitle())
            .SetColor (Annot.GetColor())
            .SetDate (Annot.GetDate())
        End With
        Debug.Print Part2Document.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\dell\Downloads\trial\Shell Pressure Drop.pdf")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Now the issue is mainly with adding annotations to `DocPage2`. In most pdf files, it didn't work. It worked only in a specific file and **only for its first page but not for other pages.**

I would really appreciate it if someone knows the solution to this issue **OR** a better solution, in general, to import comments from one pdf file to another using VBA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have started to find a solution to the issue and annots started to be transferred. However they are all messed up as you are saying although I am copying to a file with same format and setting the coordinates as the ones of the old file. However annots get rotated and many lines and shapes aren't transferred.
But they can be done seamlessly through the import data file or import comments option in adobe GUI. So they are supposed to be done easily through coding. I am not sure if there is a function whether in VBA or Javascript that imports annotations the same as it is done in the GUI.

Comment: The case here is that I am having a task to make a composite pdf file including annotations from several file versions (same pdf files with same structures but getting comments from different people). This is done usually through Adobe Acrobat using Import Data File option importing comments from each file, which would take a lot of time with a huge number of files in addition to lots of distractions.
So my intention here is to automate this process by importing all the needed files with a VBA script. I am wondering how this option (Import Data File) is available on GUI only.

Comment: Just I couldn't get your point here: "import is too easy as open the text with wrong values"